# How to wait for the WebDriver to fully load a page?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I have a webpage and it contains around 150 elements . There are buttons, text boxes, links, labels etc.. I need to wait for the driver to load all controls/Elements on the page completely. I tried to wait for a particular Element, but it does not sound good. What do I have to do to wait for the driver to load the page completely?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 60);
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conditionCheck = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            return ((input.findElements(By.id("id_of_element").size() > 0) &&     (input.findElements(By.id("id_of_element2").size() > 0) && (MORE ELEMENT CHECKS HERE) );
        }
    };
    myWait.until(conditionCheck);
```

Comment: This code is used to wait for particular Element for particular time. I don't know which element loads last. how can i know page loads completely.

Comment: Just check all the elements using "and" like I updated my comment.